# Biztalk 2009 HL7 accelerator

Tags: biztalk, hl7, biztalk-2009

1. In BizTalk 2009 HL7 accelerator how does a party resolution happen when send port is added to a party, will contents of MSH (Message Header Section) still get evaluated ?
2. What is the difference between one way MLLP (Minimum Lower Layer Protocol) and a two way MLLP?

Answer (score 0):

1. When a message is sent over that send port which you have registered with the party, everything in the MSH is processed as normal, but you have the option to populate certain fields using the BTAHL7 configuration explorer which will override anything going to your message recipient. This allows you to have 1-off MSH values per vendor if you have a canonical hl7 message coming from an orchestration or internal source of record.
2. One-Way MLLP (as is implied by the name) handles one-way communication for hl7 messages over MLLP. Two-Way allows you to send acknowledgements (ACK) as part of the message receipt process. Since some ([sic] many) vendors require acknowledgements for individual messages, you can either use two One-Way adapters or a single Two-Way adapter to accomplish that goal.
3. [How Messages Flow through BTAHL7(MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee409436.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answers parrotsquawk
May be i did not put it in proper context.
My query is w.r.t following scenario.
I  have a sendport S1 on which i send some messages to X1 vendor and there is  party configured for X1
i have another sendport S2 which send messages to X2 with different party configuration
both these  work individually fine with repective overrides
Now in the BTadmin console i open  the part X2 and add Sendport S1 then how is the behaviour?
 content wise X1 should get validated but association of port is with X2

Comment: I think I would need more information, this seems pretty vague.